# Automatically Rebuild Android Studio Project on Gradle Sync

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

How do you run a Gradle command everytime the project syncs (though the sync button after changing Gradle files)? Specifically, I would like to run "Rebuild project" or "clean, generateSources".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to View->Tool window->Gradle
There you can pick the gradle task you want and right click it and choose execute before sync

You can also create a shortcut to that task

Answer (score 0):

At Time of gradle process you can't rebuild project you should wait for completion.

But to rebuild project from android studio follow these steps:

```
1)Go to Build(alt + B)
2)Click on Rebuild.
```

If you want to sync gradle then follow below steps:

```
1)Go to Tools(alt + T)
2)Android ->
3)Now click on Sync Project with Gradle File
(OR from toolbar click on gradle icon which right of AVD Manager)
```